# How to set file permissions in windows through the command prompt mode?

Tags: windows, command-prompt

How to set the same file permissions in windows through the command prompt mode ?

Comment: Beside attrib you can use cacls or icacls http://ss64.com/nt/cacls.html

Comment: When I used cacls in Win7, this message shown, "NOTE: Cacls is now deprecated, please use Icacls."

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
>attrib /?
Displays or changes file attributes.

ATTRIB [+R | -R] [+A | -A ] [+S | -S] [+H | -H] [drive:][path][filename]
       [/S [/D]]

  +   Sets an attribute.
  -   Clears an attribute.
  R   Read-only file attribute.
  A   Archive file attribute.
  S   System file attribute.
  H   Hidden file attribute.
  [drive:][path][filename]
      Specifies a file or files for attrib to process.
  /S  Processes matching files in the current folder
      and all subfolders.
  /D  Processes folders as well.
```